# How to set an observable inside a function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to pass an observable to a function.

```
function toggleContent(switcher) {
  if (switcher == false) {
    alert(switcher); //this shows the value
    switcher(true);  //this creates an error
    switcher = true; //this doesn't do anything
  }
}

this.content = ko.observable(false);
this.registerClick = toggleContent(this.content());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the observable itself, you are currently passing only its value. Use

```
this.registerClick = toggleContent(this.content);
```

instead of

```
this.registerClick = toggleContent(this.content());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the "registerClick" to an event, do not pass any value.

```
this.registerClick = function(){
    console.log(arguments); // you can get anything expected.
};
```

Hope it helps.